# query json data from oracle 12.1 having fields value with "."

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle12.1

I have a table that has JSON data stored and I'm using `json_exists` functions in the query. Below is my sample data from the column for one of the rows.

```
{"fields":["query.metrics.metric1.field1",
           "query.metrics.metric1.field2",
           "query.metrics.metric1.field3",
           "query.metrics.metric2.field1",
           "query.metrics.metric2.field2"]}
```

I want all those rows which have a particular field. So, I'm trying below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE JSON_EXISTS(fields, '$.fields[*]."query.metrics.metric1.field1"');
```

It does not give me any results back. Not sure what I'm missing here. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if you are asking the question incorrectly, or if you are expecting the wrong result. You say you want all the rows which have a particular **field**. This means a particular node (property) **name**. However, in your "desired result" you seem to want to find a particular **value** (in a specific location), not a particular "property name" (a.k.a. "field"). So, which is it? I assume you really want to search for a particular value, not property name, but please confirm one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@` operator which refers to an occurrence of the array `fields` such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table    
 WHERE JSON_EXISTS(fields, '$.fields?(@=="query.metrics.metric1.field1")')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=34fd603ed4c3811fcb1a5daa91fbc781)</kbd>

Edit : The above case works for `12R2+`, considering that it doesn't work for your version(`12R1`), try to use `JSON_TABLE()` such as

```
SELECT fields
  FROM my_table,   
  JSON_TABLE(fields, '$.fields[*]' COLUMNS ( js VARCHAR2(90) PATH '$' )) 
 WHERE js = 'query.metrics.metric1.field1'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce642c1d4005bbaa23103f786516959b)</kbd>

Comment: The point could be explained a little further. The "path" looks for nodes (specifically, for property **names**). The OP wants to find occurrences of certain **values**. To apply conditions on *values* he must evaluate *filters*. That is what you are showing him in your query; the `@` syntax is part of that, but it's not the whole concept, or even the most important part of it.

Comment: I had already tried this query and it gives me "JSON syntax error" .  I thought I'm not able to write the query correctly. I'm using Oracle 12.1. Is there any other way or I'm missing something here?

Comment: well, it properly works in my DB which has version 12R2. Unfortunately I have no opportunity to reach 12R1 @rishi . Did you try by using `JSON_TABLE()`..?

Comment: @rishi - JSON support was new in Oracle 12.1, and it did not include support for filter expressions. That was added in Oracle 12.2. You could see that for yourself if you compared the documentation for `JSON_EXISTS` for both versions. To solve your problem, you can use the other answer, by Petr - using `json_table`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Yes. The json_table one works fine. But if you can answer one more thing. The query is very slow. Right now, I've 1M records but "fields" column is very big in size. This column is of CLOB type. What type of index should I create on it?

Comment: @rishi I don't think it's a proper way to create index for such type of data. Rather, create a new table by seperating each values within the array through use of `JSON_TABLE()` without WHERE clause **once** even if slow. And then you might create indexes, which might be of type bitmap , for new table.

Comment: @rishi - one answer uses filter expressions, which don't work in your version. Another answer (by another poster), given almost at the same time, gives the `json_table` answer, which is the one that works. So why is the "correct answer" the one that doesn't work for you, while Petr's answer is not? Keep it 100% please.

Comment: @rishi - also, if you need to index the JSON data directly (which is in some cases the right thing to do), you can, even in Oracle 12.1. But you need to learn how on your own - SO is not the right place. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6394

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to "pattern match" on the array element, but just parsing the whole thing and filtering does the job.

```
with t(x, json) as (
  select 1, q'|{"fields":["a", "b"]}|' from dual union all
  select 2, q'|{"fields":["query.metrics.metric1.field1","query.metrics.metric1.field2","query.metrics.metric1.field3","query.metrics.metric2.field1","query.metrics.metric2.field2"]}|' from dual
)
select t.*
from t
where exists (
  select null
  from json_table(
    t.json,
    '$.fields[*]'
    columns (
      array_element varchar2(100) path '$'
    )
  )
  where array_element = 'query.metrics.metric1.field1'
);
```

In your code, you are accessing the field `"query.metrics.metric1.field1"` of an object in the `fields` array, and there is no such object (the elements are strings)...

Comment: How to "pattern match" on *values* - B. Ozhan showed in the other answer. But your approach is 100% valid. In fact, if there are several calls to `json_exists` (and/or to `json_value`, `json_query` etc.), a single call to `json_table` is more efficient as it only parses the JSON once. And, in fact, except perhaps in Oracle 12.1, the optimizer would rewrite the query to use only one `json_table` call, exactly as you are doing explicitly here. This also has the advantage that we only need to learn one function instead of four. :-)